# Would Buck Strickland's scheme work?

Tags: realism, king-of-the-hill

In the episode Hanky Panky, Buck Strickand, anticipating his upcoming divorce, devises a way to avoid turning over half of ownership of a restaurant he owns by selling it to Hank Hill for petty cash with the expectation that after said divorce is finalized Hank will sell it back to him-"Ms Liz can't have half of what I 'don't' own".

Could Buck actually pull this off under Texas divorce law?

Comment: In reality , if you don't own something, that something cannot taken away from **you**. But if you owe that something to someone, then I think legally you're bound to either get that something for yourself and give it to the person you owe, or pay/provide something equally valuable

Comment: That depend on few factors: if the BBQ was established before the marriage (if not then it would be community property and to sell it he would need wife approval). Also if the sell was made during the divorce of just before it could be proven to be "split avoiding" practice (especially if he sold if for petty money).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly this is better suited to Law.SE - but at the very least this is **hiding assets** (and probably fraud) so it would be either disallowed or at worst illegal.

> **Penalties for Concealing Assets**
>
> A spouse that hides assets could face a range of consequences.  A divorce judge confronted with a spouse that has concealed assets could order the innocent spouse receive a greater share of the community assets than he or she would otherwise have received, even splitting assets 70/30, in favor of the innocent spouse, in some instances.  Further, depending on the financial actions taken, the spouse caught hiding assets could face charges from the IRS.
>
> <sup>https://nstexaslaw.com/lawyer/2018/01/23/Divorce/The-Consequences-of-Hiding-Assets-in-a-Divorce_bl32970.htm</sup>